# Replacing all html content with base64 image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom, base64

I'm looking for a way to use JS to replace the entire content of the HTML document with a single image, whose source is a *base64* string.

When you load up a URL directly in your browser, it exhibits certain properties when it is displayed. For example, the image is aspect-scaled to fit, until clicking the image which enlarges it, if it's bigger than the window size.

However, if I simply do something like...

```
document.write('<img src="data:image/png;base64,..." />');
```

...the image will display, but it won't exhibit those "native" characteristics, for lack of a better term.

Is there a way to tell the browser to replace all of its content with a base64-encoded image? Or, alternatively, perhaps some way to mimic the native image behavior as closely as possible?

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to redirect the browser to the data url. You're abandoning any control over the content, and different browsers have different limitations. If I were you, I'd look for an existing JS library that does similar things.

Comment: The issue with directing to the data url for my application is that large images have massive base64 strings, and that really tends to slow the browser down.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use document.write. First, it results in the problem you're experiencing. Second, it's slow and insecure. Use the DOM when possible like so:

```
// Store list of all child elements
var list = document.body.children;
// Loop through list
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // Use native DOM method to remove child
    document.body.removeChild(list[i]);
}
// Use native DOM method to create an image element
var img = document.createChild('IMG');
// Set the src of that image to your string
img.src = 'base64string';
// Use native DOM method to append image to document body
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. It still exhibits the behavior I'm seeing (on Chrome), which is that images larger than the browser window don't automatically shrink, nor do they have the "click to enlarge/shrink" feature that native image URLs do.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were trying to do, which is impossible because the functionality to which you're referring is a function of your browser, not of JavaScript or the DOM. As @lonesomeday says above, something like `window.location.href = 'data:image/png;base64...'` will do what you want. Again however, you will lose any scripting control over the page at this point.